# How to remove dead space in responsive lists that use flex-wrap

Tags: css, sass

I have the following Problem. I have two columns of items. One column only has one item and the first one can have multiple items. Depending on the size of the screen of an user i need the list of items to wrap. I am doing this using flex-wrap=wrap. The problem that i have is that when the screen size does not match up exactly with the size of the items and they break over there is always leftover dead space that creates a massive gap. I would like to remove this gap and center both columns. Here is example code that can be used to recreate the problem:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  .left {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .right {
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
  }
  .item {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100px;
  }
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="red item"></div>
    <div class="green item"></div>
    <div class="blue item"></div>
    <div class="yellow item"></div>
    <div class="red item"></div>
    <div class="green item"></div>
    <div class="blue item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="red item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you able to use css grid? if so then the problem can be fixed I think with it

Comment: Hey Dolev yes i am able to use a css grid

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you want?
there is also a possible solution with grid and media queries probably that maybe be a better solution for your needs.

let me know if you need more help

I gave the parent also a display flex with some properties related to it and it auto adjusts let me know if this is the behavior you want

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Center items vertically */
  justify-content: center; /* Center items horizontally */

}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px; /* Optional: Adds space between items */
}

.right {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
 // flex-grow: 1; /* Allow items to grow to fill space */
}

.red { background: red; }
.green { background: green; }
.blue { background: blue; }
.yellow { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="red item"></div>
    <div class="green item"></div>
    <div class="blue item"></div>
    <div class="yellow item"></div>
    <div class="red item"></div>
    <div class="green item"></div>
    <div class="blue item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="red item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly your solution does not seem to fix the problem. The goal would be to remove the space between the Items in the left div and the item in the right div. At the end we went with a solution that just sets the width of the left div depending on how many items we have. But i dont think that we found the optimal solution yet.